# pandas assign value in range to category

Tags: python, pandas

I have two Series, where I want to replace the values in s1 by the categorical index from s2 (which is always sorted from small to big). The first index should be returned where the value from s1 is bigger than the value from s2:

```
s1 = pd.Series([-0.225, -0.5321, 0.2341, 0.467])
0   -0.2250
1   -0.5321
2    0.2341
3    0.4670

s2 = pd.Series(data=[-0.9, -0.6, -0.45, -0.2, 0.1, 0.3, 0.55, 0.9, 1.1, 1.4],index=list('ABCDEFGHIJ'))
A   -0.90
B   -0.60
C   -0.45
D   -0.20
E    0.10
F    0.30
G    0.55
H    0.90
I    1.10
J    1.40
```

Expected output:

```
0  C
1  B
2  E
3  F
```

This is similar to the VLOOKUP function in excel (using range lookup=True).
How can this be achieved using pandas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about `pd.Series.searchsorted`?

```
>>> s2.index[s2.searchsorted(s1) - 1]
Index(['C', 'B', 'E', 'F'], dtype='object')
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to work when value in s1 is smaller than minimum value in s2.

Comment: @user6538642 Ah, I see, the smallest value. Can you add a dummy value at the start of the series?

Answer (score 1):

I think need [`cut`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.cut.html):

```
s1 = pd.Series([-0.225, -0.5321, 0.2341, 0.467, 1.8])


df = pd.cut(s1, bins=s2.append(pd.Series([np.inf])), labels=s2.index)
print (df)
0    C
1    B
2    E
3    F
4    J
dtype: category
Categories (10, object): [A < B < C < D ... G < H < I < J]
```

Comment: I like this solution, but if I set any of the values in s1 to  a value higher than 1.5, it returns NaN, where it should return J.

Comment: @user6538642 - I add new value `np.inf`

Answer (score 0):

```
def comparer(value, data=s2):
    temp = data[data <= value].index
    return temp[-1]

In [100]: s1.apply(comparer)
Out[100]: 
0    C
1    B
2    E
3    F
dtype: object
```